# AJAX: Syntax error with HTML5-doctype

Tags: ajax, html

I´m requesting a page like:

```
        $.ajax({
            type    : "GET",
            cache   : true,
            url     : './'+filename,
            dataType: "html",
            async:    false,
            // Put content in document
            success: function(response){

                console.log(response);
                return;
            }
        });
```

So if I load the page with the above code, I´ll get a error message in console: "Syntax-Error: test.html:1". Line 1 in test.html is `<!doctype html>`. What is the problem with this HTML5-doctype? Why does my AJAX load fail if I use this doctype?

Comment: Try saving your file in notepad++ encoding type `utf-8 without BOM`

Comment: unfortunately that did not solve the problem

Comment: I faced same issue many times and usually its because of BOM character, couple of years ago I spent like a week on this problem, locally every thing worked, but on server this error was occuring my first line was php.

Comment: if you can show a bit more of your code we might figure something out

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I´m developing offline and if I´m putting the files online, the problem will not occur. But I don´t know a solution, because it must work online offline :(

Comment: *correct: only offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this into the AJAX-request and the problem was solved:

```
mimeType: "text/html"
```